# Eclipse (ctrl+space) content assist hook

Tags: eclipse, plugins, shortcut, content-assist

I wrote a plugin that gets user input from Java editor, makes some computation, and writes the results to my view. The way I start the process of aforementioned computation is via context menu and I hate it. I would like it to start on ctrl+space, i.e. content assist. It is faster, more intuitive w.r.t. what the plugin does. Is there a way to do so?

Update:
For example, what should I do to get the current cursor position when user presses ctrl+space? I would use that position info and print it to my view. This is the most simplistic plugin that I basically need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take part in the content assistent calculation of Ctrl-Space by extending [javaCompletionProposalComputer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html). However, if you want to trigger some arbitrary modification operation on the Java file, you are better suited by providing a [quick assist](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_quickAssistProcessors.html) instead.

If you are confused by the terms: An example for quick assist is the suggestion "Invert if statement", which you can see when pressing Ctrl-1 with the cursor placed on an "if".

Comment: I don't want to contribute to content assist menu; I just want to trigger my methods when user presses ctrl+space. I don't want to change content assist since users are accustomed to current interface; I will add my results to my view. I updated the opening post, if that helps.

Comment: This is the answer; I am not obliged to add anything. Hook is a sessionStarted method of IJavaCompletionProposalComputer class.